# Rails 4 accepts_nested_attributes_for for has_many through relationship: :_destroy is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, foreign-key-relationship

In a Rails 4.1.6 app:

Short description: the _destroy attribute, when set to true or 1, isn't deleting the association in a has_many through relationship.

Details:
Following https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms's description of setting up a has_many through relationship, I eventually arrived with this code:

deck.rb:

```
class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :beacon_owner

  # Beacon relationship.
  has_many :deck_pointers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :beacons, through: :deck_pointers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deck_pointers, allow_destroy: true

  # Card relationship.
  has_many :card_pointers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cards, through: :card_pointers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :card_pointers, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

card.rb:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :beacon_owner
  belongs_to :template

  # Deck relationship.
  has_many :card_pointers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :decks, through: :card_pointers
  ...
end
```

card_pointer.rb:

```
class CardPointer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :deck

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :card, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

There is a similar has_many through relationship between decks and beacons:

beacon.rb:

```
class Beacon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :beacon_owner
  has_many :deck_pointers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :decks, through: :deck_pointers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deck_pointers, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end
```

deck_pointer.rb:

```
class DeckPointer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :beacon
  belongs_to :deck

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :beacon, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

In RSpec tests for the decks_controller, POST and PUT seem to properly update - **but PUT fails when I try to delete an association.** Reading http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html, I am aware of using the _destroy attribute, but it doesn't work.

My strong parameters - the `deck_params` - in my decks_controller may be wrong, but I'm not sure what might need changing:

```
class API::V1::DecksController < API::BaseController
  before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!, except: [:show]
  before_action :set_deck, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  ...
  def create
    @deck = Deck.new(deck_params)
    @deck.beacon_owner_id = current_beacon_owner.id
    @deck.save
    respond_with(@deck)
  end

  def update
    @deck.update(deck_params)
    respond_with(@deck)
  end
  ...

  private
    def set_deck
      @deck = Deck.find(params[:id])
    end

    def deck_params
      params.require(:deck).permit(:name,
        deck_pointers_attributes: [:id, :beacon_id, :deck_id, :_destroy],
        card_pointers_attributes: [:id, :card_id, :deck_id, :_destroy])
        # {deck_pointers_attributes: [:id, :beacon_id, :deck_id, :_destroy]},
        # {card_pointers_attributes: [:id, :card_id, :deck_id, :_destroy]})
    end
end
```

My test is written like this:

```
    it "updates the deck with fewer cards and beacons, deleting card/deck pointers" do
      deck = FactoryGirl.create :deck, name: 'Deck 1', beacon_owner_id: current_beacon_owner.id
      beacon1 = FactoryGirl.create :beacon, name: 'Beacon 1', uuid: 'abcd', beacon_owner_id: current_beacon_owner.id
      beacon2 = FactoryGirl.create :beacon, name: 'Beacon 2', uuid: 'efgh', beacon_owner_id: current_beacon_owner.id
      card1 = FactoryGirl.create :card, title: 'Card 1', beacon_owner_id: current_beacon_owner.id
      card2 = FactoryGirl.create :card, title: 'Card 2', beacon_owner_id: current_beacon_owner.id

      FactoryGirl.create :deck_pointer, deck_id: deck.id, beacon_id: beacon1.id
      FactoryGirl.create :deck_pointer, deck_id: deck.id, beacon_id: beacon2.id
      FactoryGirl.create :card_pointer, deck_id: deck.id, card_id: card1.id
      FactoryGirl.create :card_pointer, deck_id: deck.id, card_id: card2.id

      assert Deck.find_by_id(deck.id).cards.count == 2
      assert Deck.find_by_id(deck.id).beacons.count == 2
      assert CardPointer.count == 2
      assert DeckPointer.count == 2

      # TODO - why doesn't this change?
      puts '-----------------------------------------'
      puts "card pointer count: #{CardPointer.count}"
      puts "deck pointer count: #{DeckPointer.count}"
      puts "deck.cards.count: #{Deck.find_by_id(deck.id).cards.count}"
      puts "deck.beacons.count: #{Deck.find_by_id(deck.id).beacons.count}"
      puts '-----------------------------------------'

      put :update, format: :json, id: deck.id, deck: {
        name: "Updated Deck",
        card_pointers_attributes: [
          { card_id: card1.id, _destroy: true },
        ],
        deck_pointers_attributes: [
          { beacon_id: beacon1.id, _destroy: true },
          { beacon_id: beacon2.id, _destroy: true }
        ]
      }
      puts '-----------------------------------------'
      puts "card pointer count: #{CardPointer.count}"
      puts "deck pointer count: #{DeckPointer.count}"
      puts "deck.cards.count: #{Deck.find_by_id(deck.id).cards.count}"
      puts "deck.beacons.count: #{Deck.find_by_id(deck.id).beacons.count}"
      puts '-----------------------------------------'
      assert Deck.find_by_id(deck.id).cards.count == 1
      assert Deck.find_by_id(deck.id).beacons.count == 0

      assert CardPointer.count == 1
      assert DeckPointer.count == 0
   end
```

Am I misunderstanding something conceptually? I think I have the allow_destroy and strong parameters right... but maybe not, because that is the only thing I can think of that is incorrect.

Comment: Well, never mind - I just implemented it manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete the parent directly so that the child also gets deleted.Else you can directly delete the child ...such as

```
@user=User.first
//get any random client
client=Client.find 20
//delete child directly
@user.clients.delete(client)
```

**Moreover...you need to check if both parent/child is present because test database gets reset after every test is done.**